# Undefined trying to access a value inside an object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, types, axios

I made the request in the global state and now I want to use it to display the data when opening the option to edit the table, but when I try to call the object inside the useForm, it returns an undefined value.

When I console `user[0].name`, it returns the data I need, but when I try to put this value on the form object, the value turns into undefined.

Is there an especific way to put the data inside the form?

```
function GlobalState(props) {

    const [getId, setGetId] = useState('')

    const user = useRequestData([], `${BASE_URL}?id=${getId}`)

    const data = {
        getId,
        setGetId,
        user
    }

    return(
        <GlobalStateContext.Provider value={data}>
            {props.children}
        </GlobalStateContext.Provider>
    )
}

function DataTable() {
  const { users, filterData, showUserBy, setGetId } = useContext(GlobalStateContext);
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false)


  const handleOpenModal = (id) => {
    setOpen(true);
    setGetId(id)
  };

  return (
    <div>
        
      <TableContainer>
        <table>
          <thead>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {users
              .map((user: any) => (
                <tr key={user.id}>
                  <td>
                    <IconButton onClick={() => handleOpenModal(user.id)}>
                      <EditRoundedIcon />
                    </IconButton>

                    <IconButton onClick={() => deleteClient(user.id)}>
                      <DeleteOutlineRoundedIcon />
                    </IconButton>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              ))}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </TableContainer>
      <Modal
        open={open}
        aria-labelledby="modal-modal-title"
        aria-describedby="modal-modal-description"
      >
        <EditUser
        />
      </Modal>
    </div>

)


function EditUser(){

    const {user} = useContext(GlobalStateContext)

    const [nameUser, setName] = useState(user[0]?.name)
    
    const [form, handleInputChange, clear] = useForm({
        name: nameUser,
        company: "",
        email: "",
        phone: "",
        adress: "",
        note: "",
        isActive: true,
      });

      const onSubmitForm = (e: any) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        createUser();
      };
  
    
    return(
        <>{user === [] ? <h4>Loading...</h4> : 
        <CreateUserModal>
        <FormContainer>
          <FormHeader>
            <HeaderButton>
              <IconButton 
            //   onClick={props.onClose}
              >
                <CloseIcon />
              </IconButton>
            </HeaderButton>
            <FormTitle>
              <h3>Data</h3>
              <hr />
            </FormTitle>
          </FormHeader>
          <form onSubmit={onSubmitForm}>
            <InputContainer>
              <TextField
                name={"name"}
                value={form.name}
                onChange={(handleInputChange)}
                required
                color="secondary"
                margin="normal"
              />
              <TextField
                name={"company"}
                value={form.company}
                onChange={handleInputChange}
                color="secondary"
                margin="normal"
              />
</InputContainer>
</FormContainer>
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with how `useRequestData` works (is that a library Hook or one you have written specifically for your own project?), but I would guess from the name and the fact you pass in a URL that it is making an asynchronous request, and I further assume that the empty array you pass as its first argument is probably the value that will be returned before that request is completed. In that case, `user[0]` will indeed be undefined for the period before the request completes. You simply can't avoid that, and are correctly guarding with the `?.` - so I'm not sure what the problem is.

Comment: When you do `console.log(user[0]?.name)`, does it always print the right value, or does it first print `undefined` and then the correct value?

Comment: @Anton It prints first undefined and then the correct value.

Comment: @RobinZigmond Yes, the useRequestData is a Hook that i've writen for this project for the requisitions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you're request isn't completed the first time you render `EditUser`. This means that the first time the component renders we have `user[0]` being `undefined`. Directly after that the request is completed and `user[0]` gets a value. The code in `EditUser` (including the snippet below) is run twice, first with `user[0]` being `undefined`, and then again with the value.

What causes the error here is that the argument passed in to `useState` is only used the first time, after that the state can only be changed with the setState function. So `nameUser` is set to `undefined` on first render and not modified after that.

If you want to update the state when `user[0]` changes, you can use a `useEffect`. This snippet tells react to update the state whenever `user[0]` changes (second argument to `useEffect`).

```
useEffect(() => {
  setName(user[0]?.name)
}, [user[0]]);
```